# Bootstrap wont put image and text in the middle side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have try to put image in the right side and text in the left side,
but for some reason its the opposite and I don't know why,
By the way how can I shrink it to fit the "Can you see the simplicity behind the logo?" size.

[Link to website](http://www.simple-cap.com)

Comment: Please share the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column you want on the left should come first. So in this case the text.

Example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        [text]
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        [image]
    </div>
</div>
```

You have the img-responsive class on the logo so it will scale depending on the viewport size. You also have a inline style with "height: 200px". Lowering this number would decrease the size of the logo.

Answer (score 0):

The styles coming from bootstrap are setting your layout. For instance your image `<img src="Isaac.png" alt="" id="img_q" class="col-xs-6 text-right">` has a float:left coming from bootstrap. You can override bootstrap styles by putting your styles inline like this `<img src="Isaac.png" alt="" id="img_q" class="col-xs-6 text-right" style="float: right;">` or by placing !important; after the styles you want to override other styles. Use the developer tool on the browser to analyze the css and you'll see what is affecting your page and what is not.